# What bonuses do beds give in Survival mode?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4's Survival Mode, the only place you can save are beds, and according to the developers, different beds have varying amounts of bonuses, with sleeping bags and the like having lower bonuses than real mattresses and beds.

> **Bed Types:** The type of bed you're sleeping in limits the length of time you are able to sleep, thereby limiting how much you can recover. Real beds – which are hard to come by in the world – offer the highest bonuses for sleeping; this rewards you for working out of a home base or even spending the caps for a good night’s sleep.
>   Also, finding a sleeping bag in the middle of a dungeon will feel great… finding a dirty mattress will feel even better… finding a real bed will be like winning the lottery. You know all those spots where you can use Workshop mode in the game? It’s time to start building beds.

However, they don't clarify what kind of bonuses there are for sleeping in a comfier bed or a more broken down bed.

What are the exact bonuses for beds in the game? Which one can keep me healthier and less fatigued?

Comment: This is not off-topic as it was released publicly in Steam Beta program- check the beta tab under FO4 if you have season pass.

Comment: [Public beta content is on topic per meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any sources, I ran some experiments:

It seems that the only difference between bed types is how long you can sleep in them.

From my tests, the maximum sleeping time in a settlement is:

- Sleeping Bag: 3 hours
- Mattress: 5 hours
- Bed: 24 hours

You can set any number of hours in the sleep screen, but after the maximum, the game cancels the sleep and gives you a `You can't sleep more than [5] hours in a [dirty mattress]` message.

According to my test, to remove the `Fatigued` debuff, you need to sleep for at least 7 hours at one time; sleeping multiple times at a sleeping bag or mattress did not remove the debuff, so a sleeping bag or mattress can be used to save the game but not to remove fatigue.

To get the `Well Rested` perk (which, in addition to the 10% experience bonus, also gives you +2 End and +2 Agi in the new Survival mode), you need to sleep for 7 hours or more. It also seems that extreme hunger or thirst can prevent you from getting the perk, but I don't have time to test that thoroughly.

Comment: +1, I haven't been able to get the Well Rested perk sleeping in anything other than a bed, which matches what you have here if sleeping for 7 hours straight is needed, and you can't sleep for 7 hours without a bed. It seems like going to sleep without being well fed and properly hydrated prevents becoming well rested.